# Does virtual host root directory get picked after accept() call?

Tags: c, apache, sockets

Apache2 configuration(below) of two virtual hosts on same IP in file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

---

Binary `apache2` will be listening , something like, `listen(listenFD, 5)`.

`listenFD` should look like,

`retval = bind(listenFD, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));`
 where `servaddr.sin_port = htons(80);`

With given `accept()` call syntax,

`connfd = accept(listenFD, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &clilen);`

**Question:**

Does `httpd` server decide picking corresponding virtual host's `DocumentRoot` after `accept()` call? Is *virtual host* pick an *application layer* logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The virtual host cannot be resolved until the `Host:` HTTP header field is parsed by the server, which is obviously after `accept()` and after some amount of data has been read on the connected socket.

Comment: Yup `Host` field definition in  request header has virtualhost info